# Loading numbers back from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

I am trying to save the high score of my game. I am saving it as

```
localStorage.highScore = hscore;
```

I can see it being saved when I use the chrome dev tools. I have been trying to loadit back using:

```
hscore = localStorage.highScore;
```

When I load it back (after refreshing/re opening game) it comes up as 'type undefined'. The highscore I am trying to save is just an `Integer`.

Comment: Check to make sure `localStorage.clear()` isn't being called anywhere.

Comment: `hscore = +localStorage.highScore||0;` will give back a number, whereas before you were getting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what may be your issue. But please find a simple demo here: http://jsbin.com/liquvoxure/1/

Its better to use API style of setting/getting items.

Also check if you have exceeded any localstorage quota in your browser.

For fail-safe check if the item is truly set, before trying to fetch it.